# how to stop redirecting from my domains to primary server domain

Tags: redirect, server

I'm having issues reaching one of my server
i add 3 websites domain on server from control panel webuzo 
but all domains redirect automatic to primary server domain

Answer (score 0):

This should be configured in your web server's configuration, if you know what web server you have and how to configure it properly you can google it (sry this isn't really a answer)

EDIT: Since you have Apache2, you should setup [Virtual Hosts](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: i have apache linux ubuntu 14

Comment: If it worked, I would appreciate it if you upvoted my answer :)

Comment: you sure that will solve my problem ?
i mean problem when host any website on my server will automatic redirect web hosting to my domain primary in server

Comment: If all your domain's ip addresses are the same as your server's, it's normal the same web page shows up for every one of them, that's why you need to setup the Virtual Hosts for multiple web pages and multiple domains. So in short multiple websites on one web server

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: Possibly you have the sites pointing to the same dir and hence the same pages are served.
Webuzo does provide a flexibility to update the vhosts, but it is recommended that you do not update it.